# What lies at fs:[0x0] on windows?

Tags: windows, nt-native-api

The TEB on 32-bit Windows is located at [`fs:[0x0018]`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/NtCurrentTeb.html). What exactly is found in those 24 bytes between fs:0 and fs:0x18? (Yes, I know this undocumented and subject to change, but it'd be interesting to know...)

Comment: You can find some info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block#Contents_of_the_TIB_.2832-bit_Windows.29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is start of [Thread Information Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) at FS:[0]. The very first field of this structure is Current Structured Exception Handling (SEH) frame.

> Thus, at FS:[0] is the pointer to ExceptionList

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/Win32Exceptions.aspx)

It is pointer to Exception Callback Functions linked list head.

BTW it is pretty [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253960%28VS.80%29.aspx) and everything from FS:[0] to FS:[0x1C] (excluding) is not part of change, it is very basic structure, MS would not change it in NT OSes.

Comment: Ah - so the TEB is contained with (or located immediately after, anyway) the TIB then.